# Select dumped multipart geometries into array with postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

i'm running the following query on a table of multipart polygons:

```
SELECT id, surface_cnrtd, array_agg(igeom)
FROM (select id, st_astext(st_pointonsurface(geom)) as surface_cnrtd, 
          st_dump(geom) as igeom from my_table where id = '10020080') sub
GROUP BY dauid, surface_cnrtd;
```

I would like to return a row with the
(id i've indicated, a point geometry for the pointonsurface, an array of the path and geometries for each individual part of the multipart polygon).    I know that polygon 10020080 is mulitpart because if I change the query to this:

```
SELECT id, surface_cnrtd, array_agg(igeom)
 FROM (select id, st_astext(st_pointonsurface(geom)) as surface_cnrtd, 
          (st_dump(geom)).path as igeom from my_table where id = '10020080') sub
 GROUP BY dauid, surface_cnrtd;
```

it returns this:

```
('10020080', 'POINT(-54.3834654151038 47.6947475)', [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19]])
```

but when I run the original query my array has only the 1st geometry, like this:

```
('10020080', 'POINT(-54.3834654151038 47.6947475)', '{"({1},0103000020E61000000..........................BC0F110C64FE3E64740)"}
```

can anyone help me get the paths and the geometry of the dumped polygon into an array?

Comment: Can you post an example for the multipolygon?

Comment: my polygon is quite large and so is the wkt,  but it is definitely multipart

Comment: Also correction my group by clause is really this:  `GROUP BY id, surface_cnrtd`

Comment: Yes, the `dauid` was indeed puzzling :-)  Did you try it with my answer? At least with this small `MULTIPOLYGON` I could split the geometries into an array.

Comment: Update:  in case anyone is interested my query actually does works, and so does the one below.  When I run both versions with psql from the commandline they return the full array of dumped geometry.  The issue is something to do with psycopg2 and the way it is returning, which is what I was using to execute my query.  I should have included that.  Sorry all.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the first query into a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html) (aka WITH clause) and then aggregate the dumped geometries as you wish:

```
WITH j AS(
SELECT 1 AS id, 'POINT(-54.3834654151038 47.6947475)'::geometry AS surface_cnrtd,
   ST_Dump('MULTIPOLYGON (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)),
           ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))') AS geom 
)
SELECT j.id, ST_AsText(j.surface_cnrtd), array_agg(j.geom)
FROM j
GROUP BY j.id, j.surface_cnrtd;


 id |              st_astext              |                                                                                                                                                                                array_agg                                                                                                                                                                                
----+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | POINT(-54.3834654151038 47.6947475) | {"({1},010300000001000000040000000000000000003E40000000000000344000000000008046400000000000004440000000000000244000000000000044400000000000003E400000000000003440)","({2},010300000001000000050000000000000000002E4000000000000014400000000000004440000000000000244000000000000024400000000000003440000000000000144000000000000024400000000000002E400000000000001440)"}
(1 Zeile)
```

If you wanna stick to your syntax ...

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText(surface_cnrtd), array_agg(igeom)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, 'POINT(-54.3834654151038 47.6947475)'::geometry AS surface_cnrtd, 
      ST_Dump('MULTIPOLYGON (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)),
           ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))') as igeom) sub
GROUP BY id, surface_cnrtd;

id |              st_astext              |                                                                                                                                                                                array_agg                                                                                                                                                                                
----+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | POINT(-54.3834654151038 47.6947475) | {"({1},010300000001000000040000000000000000003E40000000000000344000000000008046400000000000004440000000000000244000000000000044400000000000003E400000000000003440)","({2},010300000001000000050000000000000000002E4000000000000014400000000000004440000000000000244000000000000024400000000000003440000000000000144000000000000024400000000000002E400000000000001440)"}
(1 Zeile)
```